# Python - unable to assign numerical value to empty input for math calculation

Tags: python, input, range, valueerror

I am trying to create a program where the user has to input 3 numbers to be displayed by the range function. However, I am trying to assign a numerical value to when an empty input is given to one of the variables. Here is part of my code. For this section of the code, I want to assign a value of zero when the user enters empty input. However, when I try running this section of the program, I get this error: line 5, in 
    number = int(input_value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
while True:
    input_value = input("Type a number: ")
    number = int(input_value)
    if input_value.isalpha():
        print("Not a number")
        break
    else:
        if input_value is None:
            number = int(0)
            break
        else:
            if int(number):
                break
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user input is empty, `input_value` will be `""`, which python cannot convert to an integer. `number = int("")` will throw an error.

What you can do is check if the input is equal `""` and if it is, set number to 0, else convert it using `int()`.

Better yet, I would wrap `number = int(input_value)` in a try catch statement:

```
while True:
    input_value = input("Type a number: ")
    try:
        number = int(input_value)
    except:
        print("invalid input")
        break
```

So to break the loop, you'd enter something thats not a number. In this case, you'd only be storing the last input value into `number`, so it's up to you how you want to keep track of all the inputs (probably using a list).

Answer (score 0):

just a thought:

```
while True:
    input_value = input("Type a number: ")
    if input_value:
        try:
            number = int(input_value)
            break
        except:
            continue

print(number)
```